# Amazon mws Scratch pad - GetMyPriceForSKU returns request id , when will i get prices?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

Amazon mws api - Just i am trying to get the prices of a product using mws api scratch pad. I passed one parameter SellerSKUList.SellerSKU.1. It didn't return the prices and produced below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMyPriceForSKUResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetMyPriceForSKUResult SellerSKU="AUYyRIG50.011" status="Success">
  <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>GIVEN</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>return_value</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
      <SKUIdentifier>
        <MarketplaceId>GIVEN</MarketplaceId>
        <SellerId>GIVEN</SellerId>
        <SellerSKU>AUYyRIG50.011</SellerSKU>
      </SKUIdentifier>
    </Identifiers>
    <Offers/>
  </Product>
</GetMyPriceForSKUResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>0e16e0de-c9e1-4456-864b-e49f2e574575</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetMyPriceForSKUResponse>
```

Comment: The response has an empty `<Offers>` tag. So I'm guessing this merchant does not have any current offer for that item. So what is it exactly that you're asking?

Comment: Just i am trying to get the prices of a product by giving ASIN or SKU.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Product's API won't return any pricing data if the product is inactive or out of stock or is merged by different ASIN, else it should return something like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMyPriceForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetMyPriceForASINResult ASIN="B009K1T3TY" status="Success">
    <Product>
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>B009K1T3TY</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
      </Identifiers>
      <Offers>
        <Offer>
          <BuyingPrice>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>3.49</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>3.49</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </BuyingPrice>
          <RegularPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>3.49</Amount>
          </RegularPrice>
          <FulfillmentChannel>AMAZON</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
          <SellerId>XXXXXXXXXX</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>snl-mldx-pura-7700-20prs-x1a</SellerSKU>
        </Offer>
        <Offer>
          <BuyingPrice>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>3.49</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>3.49</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </BuyingPrice>
          <RegularPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>3.49</Amount>
          </RegularPrice>
          <FulfillmentChannel>MERCHANT</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
          <SellerId>XXXXXXXXX</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>mldx-pura-7700-20prs-x1a</SellerSKU>
        </Offer>
      </Offers>
    </Product>
  </GetMyPriceForASINResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>fb490da2-903b-42ec-afe5-4042e6047519</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetMyPriceForASINResponse>
```